# getParam not working on live server?

Tags: plugin-development, templating, params

Not sure what is happening but

```
{% set searchQuery = craft.request.getParam('q') %}
```

Does not seem to be working at all on a different server than staging. Anyone seen this before? Any ideas what could be preventing getParam from working? Here is what the end of my url looks like with the param: `results?q=test`

I then later try to display the search parameter like.

```
<h1 class="text-uppercase">Search Results {{searchQuery}}</h1>
```

But it only displays Search Results leaving the parameter empty... and my search results seem to be returning everything since it is basically doing a wildcard search since I'm using this below to query the matching results...

```
{% paginate craft.entries.search(searchQuery).order('score').limit(10) as entries %}
```

Everything works as expected on staging server.

Comment: Are you sure `getParam` is the issue?  What happens if you `{{ searchQuery }}` immediately after `{% set searchQuery = craft.request.getParam('q') %}`?  Does it output `test`?

Comment: Outputs nothing, just like how its not outputting in the h1 I mentioned.

Comment: Maybe some `.htaccess` rewrite rule that's dropping query strings?

Comment: It sure was, client added some odd rule.

Comment: Can you add that as an official answer?

Answer (score 3):

The client must have added a new rule which was causing the problem.

changed from

```
RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

to

```
RewriteRule (.+) index.php [L]
```

Not exactly sure why they added that but...

Comment: I encountered a similar problem.  I've been using the letter "p" as part of a search string so `www.website.com/test?p=querystring`. It worked for more 6 months and now all of a sudden it doesn't work.  Thanks to this post I looked in my .htaccess file and see this rewrite rule: `RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]` which was there by default when I installed Craft.  I changed my query string parameter to "q" and now it works again.  Not sure if something changed when I updated to the latest Craft version or if it's something else.