# getParam not working anymore

Tags: templating, params

I encountered a problem which is very similar to [this post](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/10416/getparam-not-working-on-live-server#comment23803_10442). I've been using the letter "p" as part of a search string so `www.website.com/test?p=querystring`. It worked for more 6 months and now all of a sudden it doesn't work. Thanks to [the other post](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/10416/getparam-not-working-on-live-server#comment23803_10442) I looked in my .htaccess file and see this rewrite rule: `RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]` which was there by default when I installed Craft. I changed my query string parameter to "q" and now it works again. Not sure if something changed when I updated to the latest Craft version which at the time was version 2.6.2945, or if it's something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query value for `p` has been the [pageTrigger](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#pageTrigger) since Craft 1.0 (and probably in the beta as well).

I'm not sure why you were still able to use it for other purposes up until recently. To be honest, it sounds like you were accidentally exploiting a bug, which has since been fixed.