# Craft request returns null in test, but works locally

Tags: query, querystring

I have a search that is working locally, but not when I push it to my test environment.

I imported the database from my local environment into test, so the data should exist.

The URL for each is:

test: https://mytesturl/site/?q=test

local: http://local/site/?q=test

I set the query, which returns null/empty in test, but populates correctly locally:

{% set query = craft.request.getParam('q') %}

I'm drawing a blank what could be wrong. Seems to be a config issue, but I'm not sure where to look.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This sounds similar to your issue, have a look. People provided a solution there, it apparently might have something to do with your .htaccess file.

[getParam not working on live server?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/10416/getparam-not-working-on-live-server?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Good idea. I'm using the nginx server though.